# Going to place vs going place

Tags: phrases

I am planning to go to my hometown this week. What is the proper way to tell this to some one?

> "I am going Mumbai this week"

or

> "I am going to Mumbai this week"

Or is there a native phrase that can be used here?

Answer (score 1):

`"I am going to Mumbai this week."` is correct.

As far as I know, prepositions are used before nouns like 'Mumbai', 'aunt's place', 'office', etc.

You don't need to use a preposition before verbs or adverbs. For example it is correct to say, 'I am going crazy' but, saying 'I am going to crazy' is wrong.